# How to change background color when button or div pressed and if pressed another one the first one changes color back?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have list of buttons (or div):

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1">Details1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2">Details2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn3">Details3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn4">Details4</button>
```

I want to have next:

when I press btn1 it's background color changes to white. When I press btn2 - btn2 background color becomes white and btn1 background color changes back to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution, still using jQuery :

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1" onClick="activate( this )">Details1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2" onClick="activate( this )">Details2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn3" onClick="activate( this )">Details3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn4" onClick="activate( this )">Details4</button>
```

**JS**

```
function activate( element ){
    clearAll();
    $( element ).addClass( 'active' );
}

function clearAll(){
    $( '.btn' ).removeClass( 'active' );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/33eup40e/6/

And a solution using AngularJS :

**JS**

```
angularApp.controller( 'WhiteButtonCtrl', function( $scope ){
  $scope.buttons = [
    { id: 'btn1', value: 'Details1' },
    { id: 'btn2', value: 'Details2' },
    { id: 'btn3', value: 'Details3' },
    { id: 'btn4', value: 'Details4' }
  ]
  $scope.activeBtn = undefined;

  $scope.activate = function( str ){
    $scope.activeBtn = str;
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="WhiteButtonCtrl">
  <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" ng-class="{ 'active' : activeBtn === button.id }"
          ng-click="activate( button.id )" type="button" class="btn" id="{{button.id}}">
    {{button.value}}
  </button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/33eup40e/13/

Comment: I don't use jQuery . just js and angular js. how to do it?

Comment: I just updated my answer to include an AngularJS solution example.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with background color.
Then attach a listener to every div, on click you will add that special class to them.
Every time you click div, you need to remove that class from any other div, after that, apply class to selected div.

Answer (score 0):

Get your button collections by `document.getElementsByClassName` and catch click by `addEventListener` .Also can change css background by `element.style.background`

```
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1">Details1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2">Details2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn3">Details3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn4">Details4</button>
<script>
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");    
 for(var i =0 ; i < btn.length;i++){        
        btn[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
            toggle(this.id);            
        });        
    }
 function toggle(id){
    for(var i =0 ; i < btn.length;i++){
    btn[i].style.background = "";
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = "white";
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> simply two line of code would work for your problem

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
    $('.btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1">Details1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2">Details2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn3">Details3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="btn4">Details4</button>
```